# Custom filename in a rolling Log4Net logfile?

Tags: asp.net, log4net

We have a ASP .Net application whereby we use Log4Net to log details within the app - nothing new there - and the rolling log filenames are in the usual format of:

```
rolling-log.txt 
rolling-log.txt.1
rolling-log.txt.2 etc.
```

A each user of the application adds to the logfile, the logfile can be difficult to read for a specific user's case and so, we'd like to modify the config file somehow to record the user's log details individually, each writing to a specific file, e.g.

```
<applicationId>rolling-log.txt
<applicationId>rolling-log.txt.1
<applicationId>rolling-log.txt.2
etc.
```

where  is each user's unique application Id, made up of a five digit number, e.g.

```
12345rolling-log.txt
```

Any ideas on the best way to implement this, assuming that it's possible?

Cheers

Brett

Answer (score 18, accepted):

look for log4net Context Properties...

in your code :

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["id"] = "12345";
```

then

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("configPath"));
```

in the log4net config file:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
            value="%property{id}rolling-log.txt" />
```

Answer (score 37):

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
  <conversionPattern value="C:\Logs\log-%date{ yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss}-[%processid].log" />
</file>
```

[from here](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F18380%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx)

Comment: N.B. Replace the `<param name="File" value="..." />` element with the above.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the Log4Net configuration file supports environment variables (e.g. USERNAME) as well as customizable patterns which should give you what you want.

Look at "PatternString for pattern based configuration" in [the Log4Net V1.2.10 release notes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that log file per user is possible but you can write custom layer between log4net and your application which prepends user id before writing to log.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom layout by inherit from XmlLayoutBase.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the RollingPatternFileAppender, just like the rollingfileappender plus dynamic file name 
http://mysite.verizon.net/vze14bhji

Comment: Site is no longer there.