# How can I change the file location programmatically?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am totally new to Log4net.  I have managed to get something going by adding a config file and simple logging.  I have hardcoded the value to be `"C:\temp\log.txt"` but this is not good enough.

The logs must go to the special folders

```
path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

and this path changes depending whether you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows XP or Vista etc...

How can I just change the location of the file in log4net programmatically?

This is what I have done:

```xml
<configSections>
<section name="log4net"
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>         
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\temp\log.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

---

```
class Program
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log.Warn("Log something");

        path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);


        // How can I change where I log stuff?
    }
}
```

Just need to figure out how I can change to log stuff to where I want to.

Any suggestions?
Thanks  a lot

Comment: You need to dig through your logger's IAppenders and set the FileAppender.File to your required output path. Here's a [really good example](http://insario.com/blog/jfk/archive/2004/11/30/164.aspx).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

log4net can handle this for you. Any appender property of type string can be formatted, in this case, using the [log4net.Util.PatternString](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm) option handler. PatternString even supports the [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) enum which enables the following elegant config:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
        value="%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}\\test.txt" />
    ...
</appender>
```

Here's a unit test that proofs the pudding:

```
[Test]
public void Load()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    var fileAppender = LogManager.GetRepository()
        .GetAppenders().First(appender => appender is RollingFileAppender);

    var expectedFile = 
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
                "test.txt");

    Assert.That(fileAppender, 
        Is.Not.Null & Has.Property("File").EqualTo(expectedFile));
}
```

The following test verifies that log4net actually writes to disk (which basically makes this an "integration" test, not a unit test, but we'll leave it at that for now):

```
[Test]
public void Log4net_WritesToDisk()
{
    var expectedFile = 
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
                "test.txt");

    if (File.Exists(expectedFile))
        File.Delete(expectedFile);

    XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (ConfigTest));
    log.Info("Message from test");

    LogManager.Shutdown();

    Assert.That(File.ReadAllText(expectedFile), 
        Text.Contains("Message from test"));
}
```

NB: I strongly suggest using the compact property syntax demonstrated in the above sample. Removing all those "<property name=" makes your config that much more readable.

Comment: Hi
THanks I have tried this but still does not log in application Data
I have had a look on the web I have found something called PatternString but I have no idea how to use it.
Has anybody got an example?

Comment: @brix - My initial answer didn't work, so I had to prove to myself that log4net can do this. PatternString is the solution :)

Comment: hi,tried your solution but for some reasons it does not log at all.
I have copied what you suggested.Run the app but no file created.
Does yours actually create a file?
thanks a lot

Comment: @brix - it does create the file. One thing to have in mind is that log4net will not always flush data to disk immediately. You should also check that the user running your app have enough permissions in that folder to create and write to files.

Comment: %envFolderPath{} does not appear to be part of the current (1.2.10) release of log4net.  I had to pull r606477 from their subversion repository to enable this very useful feature.  I would expect this to be included in the next (1.2.11) release.

Comment: @rschuler: I added an answer that will work with 1.2.10, see below

Comment: @rschuler : as expected %envFolderPath{} is included in release 1.2.11 and rockin'

Comment: From @JackAce's answer below, after resetting the file path, be sure to call ".ActivateOptions()" to get it to activate. Calling .file will set it but it won't be used until the ActivateOptions call

Comment: Be aware that this approach doesn't work if you are watching the log4net config file for changes (https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Config_XmlConfiguratorAttribute_Watch.htm).

Answer (score 51):

I found a mutation of this code in the interwebs:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy h =
(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository();
foreach (IAppender a in h.Root.Appenders)
{
    if (a is FileAppender)
    {
        FileAppender fa = (FileAppender)a;
        // Programmatically set this to the desired location here
        string logFileLocation = @"C:\MySpecialFolder\MyFile.log";

        // Uncomment the lines below if you want to retain the base file name
        // and change the folder name...
        //FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fa.File);
        //logFileLocation = string.Format(@"C:\MySpecialFolder\{0}", fileInfo.Name);

        fa.File = logFileLocation;
        fa.ActivateOptions();
        break;
    }
}
```

This works for me.  Our application needs to put the log file in a folder that contains the version number of the app based on the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

You should be able to set the logFileLocation programmatically (e.g. you can use Server.MapPath() if this is a web application) to suit your needs.

Comment: I feel like this give a lot more control over the file location.

Comment: yeah this is the only way to go. the other way is too confusing and i'm afraid to introduce it to the developers.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c/1535998#1535998) doesn't work for Log4net v1.2.10.0. 
An alternative method is described [here](http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=110142086820117&w=2).

Basically the method is to implement a custom pattern converter for the log4net config file.

First add this class to your project:

```
public class SpecialFolderPatternConverter : log4net.Util.PatternConverter
{
    override protected void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        Environment.SpecialFolder specialFolder = (Environment.SpecialFolder)Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), base.Option, true);
        writer.Write(Environment.GetFolderPath(specialFolder));
    }
}
```

Then set up the File parameter of your FileAppender as follows:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
    <converter>
      <name value="folder" />
      <type value="MyAppName.SpecialFolderPatternConverter,MyAppName" />
    </converter>
    <conversionPattern value="%folder{CommonApplicationData}\\SomeOtherFolder\\log.txt" />
  </file>
```

Basically the `%folder` tells it to look at the converter called `folder` which points it to the SpecialFolderPatternConverter class. It then calls `Convert` on that class, passing in the CommonApplicationData (or whatever) enum value.

Comment: Thanks for that. btw, App in MyAppName I think refers to Project rather than App.

Comment: This is the only option that works if you are watching the log4net.config file for changes (https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Config_XmlConfiguratorAttribute_Watch.htm)

Answer (score 8):

How about a simple:

```
XmlConfigurator.LogFullFilename = @"c:\ProgramData\MyApp\Myapp.log";
```

Why is it so complex to do a really simple thing?

Comment: Because, path changes depending whether you are in windows Server 2008 or winxp or vista etc... In XP there is no c:\ProgramData folder, only in Win7/Vista. So, if we are going to deploy this app it must be compatible for all OS. :-) Hard coding is not a good practice.

Comment: I'm using log4net v2.0.3 and this property isn't available on XmlConfigurator.  Must have been removed since the answer was posted.

Comment: Thanks Jason for correcting my english,  this is not my primary language ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Irshad: yes, but we can read the configuration from a database (for example). If we can change this path programmatically, sometimes it's better

Answer (score 6):

To also change the error log's path (based on JackAce's answer):

```
private static void SetLogPath(string path, string errorPath)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy h =
    (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    foreach (var a in h.Root.Appenders)
    {
        if (a is log4net.Appender.FileAppender)
        {
            if (a.Name.Equals("LogFileAppender"))
            { 
                log4net.Appender.FileAppender fa = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)a;                    
                string logFileLocation = path; 
                fa.File = logFileLocation;                   
                fa.ActivateOptions();
            }
            else if (a.Name.Equals("ErrorFileAppender"))
            {
                log4net.Appender.FileAppender fa = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)a;
                string logFileLocation = errorPath;
                fa.File = logFileLocation;
                fa.ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
..
      <file value="${APPDATA}\MyApp\MyApp Client\logs\Log.txt"/>
..
  </log4net>
```

If needing to write to special folders I found help [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#fileappender) (2nd and 3rd example).

Edit:

To answer OP.. This works for 'all users' area:

```
      ...
      <file value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\MyApp\MyApp Client\logs\Log.txt"/>
      ...
```

Which is normally "C:\ProgramData" in newer versions of Windows.

See these too:
[How to specify common application data folder for log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/468989/503621) == https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889591/503621 and comments
&
https://superuser.com/q/405097/47628
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5550502/503621

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` and `$(APPDATA)` are not the same folder

Comment: You can also try "${ALLUSERSPROFILE} " instead . .

Answer (score 4):

JackAce's answer, just more concise using Linq:

**C#**

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
var appender = (LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy).Root.Appenders
    .OfType<FileAppender>()
    .First();

appender.File = logPath;
appender.ActivateOptions();
```

**VB.NET**

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure()
Dim appender = CType(LogManager.GetRepository(), Hierarchy).Root.Appenders _
    .OfType(FileAppender)() _
    .First()

appender.File = logPath
appender.ActivateOptions()
```

Comment: In my case the first line `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` created warning outputs to the console. I just removed it and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Great use case for LINQs [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Applies a transformation to the filenames of all FileAppenders.
/// </summary>
public static void ChangeLogFile(Func<string,string> transformPath)
{
    // iterate over all FileAppenders
    foreach (var fileAppender in LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().OfType<FileAppender>())
    {
        // apply transformation to the filename
        fileAppender.File = transformPath(fileAppender.File);
        // notify the logging subsystem of the configuration change
        fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
    }
}
```

If the filename in the app.config is `log.txt` this will change the log output to `logs/some_name_log.txt`:

```
ChangeLogFile(path => Path.Combine("logs", $"some_name_{Path.GetFileName(path)}"));
```

To Answer the OPs original problem that would be:

```
ChangeLogFile(path => Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), path));
```

Comment: When I did this, it simply re-created an empty file with the new name, but then `Logger.GetLogger` continued to write to the old name instead.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to doing this programatically, you can use environment variables and customizable patterns in the configuration file.  [See this response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031096/custom-filename-in-a-rolling-log4net-logfile/1031253#1031253).

Look at "PatternString for pattern based configuration" in [the Log4Net V1.2.10 release notes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html).

Also if you are thinking of writing to a directory such as Enviroment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData you need to consider:

- Will all instances of your application for all users have write access to the log file?  E.g. I don't believe non-administrators will be able to write to Enviroment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData.
- Contention if multiple instances of your application (for the same or different users) are attempting to the same file.  You can use the "minimal locking model" (see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html to allow multiple processes to write to the same log file, but there probably will be a performance impact.  Or you could give each process a different log file, e.g. by including the process id in the filename using a customizable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Log4Net (2.0.8.0) you could simply use `<file value="${ProgramData}\myFolder\LogFiles\" />` for `C:\ProgramData\..` and `${LocalAppData}` for `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deploy to unknown systems and you want to use the simple solution by Philipp M even with different special folders you can retrieve the special folder path you want and set a custom env variable before loading the log4net configuration.

    `string localData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_FOLDER_DATA", localData);
    XmlConfigurator.Configure( ...`

... just to be sure the env variable exists and has the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking to set the file path to Project root dicrectory Path can refer below code. I have implemented this in .NET 5 API Project

Changes for Log4net.config file. Remember type="log4net.Util.PatternString" this line is very important

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LoggerFilePath}\Logs\server.log" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
</layout>
```

Then, in `Program.cs` file

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((context,loggerBuilder) => 
        {
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LoggerFilePath"] = context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            loggerBuilder.ClearProviders();
            loggerBuilder.AddLog4Net();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Make sure you include System.Linq
//Though is an answer to old question, 
//but more concise, just two lines of code. 
((FileAppender)LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().Select(a => a).First()).File = @"C:\log.txt";
((FileAppender)LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().Select(a => a).First()).ActivateOptions();
```