# Log4net .Does it work in vb6 Interop to .net?

Tags: vb6, interop, log4net

I have some legacy application in vb6 and I am interoping into .net

It all works fine in net alone but in vb6 it does not create the log.
I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

I have using log4net using config file and I have added the log4net configsection into
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\vb6.exe.config

has anybody got it working in vb6?
What are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vb6.exe.config could not possibly work since this is the VB 6 IDE, not your legacy application.

You would have to initialize and use log4net from the .net libraries you are interop'ing with.  You can do this using [XmlConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) and a separate config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
What you are saying makes total sense.It drove me mad for quite a bit till I gave up.

Are you saying 
Create a config file call it EG "Log4net.config "

In a class initialize Log4Net and use XMLCOnfigurator by pointing 
to the "Log4Net.Config"

That sounds good.
I am a total novice on log4Net and a little handle would be fantastic.
I will have a look at the xmlconfigurator and whether  you can pass a filename with full path to get to the config file.

thanks a lot

Comment: @brix - yes you can. There's a sample (the console app) at the link in my answer. Good luck! (and remember to accept my answer if you found it useful ;)

Comment: Hi,
It worked thanks a lot.One final question :)
how can I override the filename in the config file so that I can use
Enviroment.GetFolderPath
(Enviroment.SpecialFloder.CommonApplicationData)

As you know different Operating system have different places 
 the %AllUsers% in the config file does not load under ApplicationData

thanks a lot again

Comment: @brix - great coincidence there, I answered up another question related exactly to that Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c/1535998#1535998