# How can I log to a file in Common Application Data (appdata) using log4net?

Tags: log4net

I can't seem to find a definitive answer/example on how I can log to a file in appdata

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\CompanyName\ApplicationName\Logs\app.log

I don't want to "hardcode" the path in the `app.config` and would rather use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log4Net.How can I change the file location programmatically c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c/1535998#1535998). It explains in detail how to configure this path setup in log4net configuration.

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(); 
var appenders = hierarchy.GetAppenders();
  foreach (var appender in appenders)
  {
    FileAppender fileAppender = appender as FileAppender;
    if (fileAppender != null)
    {
      fileAppender.File = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData, "myLogFile.log");
      fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are plenty of acceptable (idiomatic, even) ways to do this with log4net configuration. log4net is just not built for runtime modification.