# Log4.net - how to log to 2 different files in same application?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a web application and would like to log to different files depending on which web service gets called.

So WS1 will log to WS1_log.txt for example, while WS2 will log to WS2_log.txt.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Create two (rolling) file appenders in your configuration and then configure your loggers like this:

```
<appender name="FileAppenderWebservice1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\logs\webservice1.txt" />
    ...
</appender>

<appender name="FileAppenderWebservice2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\logs\webservice2.txt" />
    ...
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="ALL" />            
</root>
<logger name="YourNameSpace.Webservice1Class">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppenderWebservice1" />
</logger>
<logger name="YourNameSpace.Webservice2Class">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppenderWebservice2" />
</logger>
```

This requires that you create a logger per webservice like this:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WebserviceClass));
```

Comment: one correction would be the name of the logger seems to be the name of my logging wrapper class without a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find your answer here [Change log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c)

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
        value="%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}\\test.txt" />
    ...
</appender>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about putting the log4net config in a web.config most local to the web service.