# How give Log4Net the name of directory in which it should logs?

Tags: c#, log4net

I receive some Data from a web service and among those data there is an attribut "BUS" which can take "CHNL_1, CHNL_3, CHNL21 ..." values.

i need that log4net create for me a folder (name is BUS value) for each BUS give it to it as parameter (string).

Env : VS.NET 2005 / C#
thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions like this (file per thread, file per request, file per user) and there is no good answer with file appenders: log4net does not really support this scenario.

My recommendation would be to log to a database, this allows you to filter your log messages quite effectively.