# Can you set a property value within the log4net config?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm working on a C# application that will have quite a few log files. These log files will be created in the same file path, and this file path will be determined at configuration time.

Is there a way I could specify this log files *basepath* in a single location the log4net configuration e.g. in a property?

I'd, of course, be referencing this basepath in the `file` param of each logfile appender?

One option I've considered is setting this path in the app.config/web.config, which the application will transfer into a log4net global context property. However, that would mean making sure that all loggers are created AFTER this property is set.

Any comments on the preferred, *or* the fallback method are welcome.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a log4net custom pattern converter to return the basepath for logfiles.  This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389828/910348.

The difference for your scenario is that your converter can simply read the basepath from your app.config/web.config.

Cheers!