# Define variables inside app.config

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

Is it possible to define variables inside the app.config file?

Maybe like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="folder">
  C:\Data\Log\
</xsl:variable>
```

... and use it in the app.config in this way:

```
<file value="$folder\ErrorLog.txt" />
```

I have some different folders inside my app.config and won't change every path one by one.

Comment: But I want to use the variable inside the app.config itself.
Not in the c#-code.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the Project in Visual Studio, and select Properties.  Then go to Settings to add settings of different data types (eg. string) there.

Also, if you're looking for a log4net-specific solution, this question/answer may help: stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736

Comment: I think that's not what I want.

I got a log4net Configuration in my app.config, it has around 300 lines and around 20 pathes with different endings (files).

My wish is to define the path (C:\Data\Log\) at a central location inside the app.config file. I won't replace it one by one or by "find and replace" every time I have to change it.

Comment: I get it now :-).  I don't think there's a way to do this within the config file alone.  I've needed to do something like this before but, I would define a Folder setting, and then various File1, File2, etc. settings.  Then in my C# code I would read the settings and build the actual file locations by appending Folder+File1, Folder+File2, etc.  I'm not sure if that will work for your log4net situation, but otherwise will allow you do define the Folder once, and reuse that for all the other files.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a log4net-specific solution, this question/answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736

Comment: No, that will not work for me, because i wont use code for the configuration. :-/ Everything should be defined in the app.config.

But maybe the second link could be helpful. I will read it later. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can define `LogBaseDir` as an environment variable and consume it in the app.config:

```
<appender name="RollingFileError" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${LogBaseDir}\ErrorLog.txt" />
  <!-- ... -->
</appender>
```