# Log4net to generate log files dynamically

Tags: c#, log4net

In my application I use log4net for logs creation. I want to create the log files in the location where the application gets installed.That is , the log files should be generated in `c:\App_Instal_path\Logs(folder)`, if the application is installed under `c:\`.If it is `D:\` then the log files should be under `D:\App_Instal_path\Logs(folder)`. I have done like:

```
<appender name="ColoredFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
<file value=***NEEDS TO BE FILLED*** />
```

Any responses would be really appreciated..

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/log4net-how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically-c

Comment: Have you tried setting the file value to "" ? or "\" ? This will save the log where the application is running from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the logfile near your exe file, if you write like this:

```
<file value="log-file.txt" />
```

In that case, you put the logfile in folder Logs, near your exe file:

```
<file value="Logs/log-file.txt" />
```

In that case, you put the logfile in system TMP folder:

```
<file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
```

Look here for more information:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: Thanks for that: In your 2nd answer it it like Logs\log-file.txt??(\ instead of /)??

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. In examples [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1052690.aspx) uses "\", but I looked config section in my work project - I use "/" here and it's work well.

Comment: @vysakh Actually .NET (i.e. the underlying Win32 API) supports both a forward slash `/` or a backslash `\\` as the directory separator in most cases. For consistency I would recommend using a backslash.