# Add variables to filename of rollingfileappender in Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

Is there a way to make the name of the fileAppender variable?
I.e. when I call an action on my controller which takes an object, I would like to write this to a log file. 
The name of the file would look something like :
yyyyMMdd_hhmssms_[controller]_[method].json

this is what I have in my config-file:

```
<appender name="JsonFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <file value="c:\temp\" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_hh.mm.ss.ms_%thread{CommonApplicationData}'.json'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

This returns the following filename : 20160224_01.30.28.3028_P1rea24{Co30onApplicaPionDaPa}.json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535736/how-can-i-change-the-file-location-programmatically

Comment: That will create one file per log entry!!

Comment: @stuartd I know, that is wat the customer wants. It's just to log the json that was sent to the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the appenders of your log4net configuration at run-time like so

```
var repository = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
var appenders = repository.GetAppenders().Where(x => x is FileAppender);
```

You can get specific appender then by name

```
var appender = appenders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("MyAppeader"));
```

Once you have an appender you can modify it how you like. You want to set the filepath

```
appender.File = @"c:\folder\yyyyMMdd_hhmssms_[controller]_[method].json";
```

You should not have the do anything else as log4net should automatically start using the new configuration.

Placing this all into a little helper method, you'd get this

```
public static void SetAppenderPath(string appender, string path)
{
    var repository = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    var appenders = repository.GetAppenders().Where(x => x is FileAppender);
    var appender = appenders.FirstOfDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(appender));
    
    if (appender == null)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Appender not found (" + appender + ")");
    }

    appender.File = path;
}

...

LogHelper.SetAppenderPath("MyAppender", @"yyyyMMdd_hhmssms_[controller]_[method].json");
```

Comment: When amending appenders in code you should always call `appender.ActivateOptions()` afterwards: some changes may not require it but others do, so it's good practise to call it every time.

Answer (score 6):

one way is to set an Environment Variable in your code like:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APPENDER_FILE", "Your File Path");
```

and then, configure this environment variable in log4net XML:

```
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${APPENDER_FILE}"/>
```

Comment: But this means that I need to set that Environment Variable when I configure the logger. So where I write : log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() ?