# Change log4net filename when running

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a program that starts smaller programs, or tasks, and now I want each task to log to their own filename dynamically, preferrably using the name of task.
I've digged around a little and it seems that there's a nifty `%property` thing that you can use with Log4Net. So I tried that. But it seems that Log4Net doesn't pickup changes for this after it has been initialized.

I wrote a little test program to play around with. 
I would prefer to only build the windsor container once, but then Log4Net won't be "reinitialized", and create a new logfile. So now I have to build the container before starting the task to be sure that I get the right filename on the logfile.

Does anyone know if there's a better/smarter way to change the filename of the log during runtime?

Here's my testcode:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "default";
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("> ");
            string cmd = (Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmd)) continue;
            if (cmd.ToLower() == "exit") Environment.Exit(0);

            ExecuteTask(Regex.Split(cmd, @"\s+"));
        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteTask(string[] args)
    {
        //This changes the filename Log4Net logs to, but Log4Net only picks it up if I rebuild my container
        GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = args[0];

        //This should only be run once. No real need to build the container before each run, except to reinitialize Log4Net
        var container = BuildContainer();
        try
        {
            var task = container.Resolve<ITask>(args[0]);
            task.DoLog();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // This doesn't work as expected, Log4Net logs to the file specified outside of the trycatch
            GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "default";
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            logger.Info("Could not find "+args[0]);
        }
    }


    private static WindsorContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(
            FromAssembly.This());

        return container;
    }
}

public interface ITask
{
    void DoLog();
}

public class TwoTask : ITask
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TwoTask(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoLog()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello!");
    }
}

public class OneTask : ITask
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public OneTask(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoLog()
    {
        _logger.Info("Hello!");
    }
}

public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                  .BasedOn(typeof(ITask))
                                  .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient.Named(c.Implementation.Name)));
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net("log4net.config"));
    }
}
```

Nugets used:
Castle.Core, Castle.Core-log4net, Castle.LoggingFacility, Castle.Windsor

Answer (score 1):

> *I want each task to log to their own filename dynamically, preferably using the name of task*

The only way to do this - assuming your tasks run concurrently - is to have one logger per task, where **each logger has it's own appender**.

As you have noticed, changing the property doesn't change the log file, as that's set at configuration time. A common solution is to patch the appender file name programmatically at run time - which is easy enough, but then because loggers share appenders, you would see one task logging into another task's file.

So you're going to have to [construct loggers and appenders at runtime](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200602.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C769745@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E) - excerpted from that post:

```
// Create a new file appender
public static log4net.Appender.IAppender CreateFileAppender(string name,
string fileName)
{
    log4net.Appender.FileAppender appender = new
    log4net.Appender.FileAppender();
    appender.Name = name;
    appender.File = fileName;
    appender.AppendToFile = true;

    log4net.Layout.PatternLayout layout = new
    log4net.Layout.PatternLayout();
    layout.ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n";
    layout.ActivateOptions();

    appender.Layout = layout;
    appender.ActivateOptions();

    return appender;
}
```

And:

```
// Add an appender to a logger
public static void AddAppender(string loggerName,log4net.Appender.IAppender appender)
{
     log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
     log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger l =
          (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)log.Logger;

      l.AddAppender(appender);
}
```

Comment: The tasks won't run in parallell, so there should not be a problem with them writing in each other's files.
If I just could get Castle.Windsor to resolve just the logger before each run I think it would be ok. But that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: In which case, you can just set the filename programmatically for each task and log4net will create a new file - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32873679/43846

Answer (score -1):

In your appenders defined in `log4net.config` you can specify an output format for the file name. For instance `<file value="fixedName"/>`. You can also have a dynamic file name by using `<staticLogFileName value="false"/>` together with a pattern, e.g.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="somePrefix-%property{SomePropertyName}-%utcdate{yyMMdd}.trace.log" />.
```

This will route to different files based on date and your `"SomePropertyName"` property.

You will have to set that propery in your tasks, like `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["SomePropertyName"] = "someValue";`.

I guess a good switch would be the name of the thread that generated the logging event (`%t` or `%thread`). Outputs the thread number if no name is available. But you could set the thread name explicitly in your `ITask`s.

Comment: All you've done really is used `ThreadContext` instead of `GlobalContext` but this still won't work - the file name is set at configuration time. You can change the value of property as much as you want, but it will have no effect.