# How to have different instances of the same application log to different files with log4net?

Tags: .net, log4net

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812880/log4net-and-logging-from-parllel-instances), but with a somewhat simpler context. In my case I have a single application which may be run twice (at most) simultaneously with different command line parameters, so each instance knows its context.

The app.config file defines a log4net section to configure logging. Here it is:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <appender name="MainAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\NCAgent.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="MainAppender" />
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

And, of course, we have a problem that two application instances may log to the same log file, so at runtime one of the instances (the choice is well defined and unambiguous) loads the log4net `XmlElement`, changes there the name of the log file and configures log4net using the `XmlConfigurator.Configure(XmlElement)` overload.

I do not like our approach and feel that there should be a better solution. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try either configuring the FileAppender filename programmatically and appending the process ID, or subclass the FileAppender to make said behavior automatic with the config-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031096/custom-filename-in-a-rolling-log4net-logfile/1031253#1031253).

You can define a pattern for the filename including something unique such as a timestamp or a process id.